# flutter gridview problem with aspect ratio on different devices

Tags: flutter, gridview

I want to have a fixed height container in gridview. I am using following code. It is showing different height on different devices. Is  there any way to control the height in a way that it look same on all devices.[image]

```
                            GridView.count(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              crossAxisCount: 2,
                              mainAxisSpacing: 0,
                              childAspectRatio:
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                                      (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1),
                              crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                              children: _productData.map((opt) {
                                return _productCard(context, opt, cart);
                              }).toList(),
                            ),
```

Comment: If you want your GridView Items to look the same on every device, you don't need `ChildAspectRatio`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by using the class here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55290
and then using it like this

```
                            GridView.builder(
                              itemCount: _productData.length,
                              gridDelegate:
                                  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCountAndFixedHeight(
                                crossAxisCount: 2,
                                crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                                mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                                height: 300.0,
                              ),
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
                                var opt = _productData[index];
                                return _productCard(context, opt, cart);
                              },
                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because, if you use "MediaQuery", it will get the size(width, height) of the device you are running it on, and you know all devices have different sizes.
So using  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1), will not give the accurate result on all devices..
i suggest you do this

```
GridView.count(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 0,
                          childAspectRatio: 2:1
                              
                          children: _productData.map((opt) {
                            return _productCard(context, opt, cart);
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
```

You can keep substituting the value of the aspect ratio till you get your desired size.

Comment: I used the class on this link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55290 and so far it is working on 3 devices and i will try your solution too. thank you

Comment: if it solved your problem, you can  consider marking it as the right answer